# Justify indirect proof rule with law of excluded middle

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

In P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (p. 174, exercise D), appears this exercise:

> D. Show that if you had **LEM** as a basic rule, you could justify **IP** as a derived rule. That is, suppose you had the proof:
>   $
> \def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
> \def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
> \def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
> \def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
> \def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
> \def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
> \def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
> \def\ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
> $
>   $$
> \fitch{}{
>  \fitch{\neg A}{
>    \ldots\\
>    \bot
>   }
> }
> $$
>
> How could you use it to prove A without using **IP** but with using **LEM** as well as all the other basic rules?

I tried to prove it in this manner:

$
\fitch{}{
 \fitch{1. \ \neg A}{
   \ldots\\
   k. \bot \\
  }\\
  \fitch{k+1.\ A}{
   A \R{k + 1}
  }\\
  \fitch{k+2. \ \neg A}{
   \bot\\
   A 
  }
}
$

Am I approaching what is requested in a proper manner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}$

> Am I approaching what is requested in a proper manner ?

Yes.

You have used Explosion (ex falso quodlibet.) and now need to use LEM and disjunction elimination.

Also if you do not wish to combine the first and third proof into one, then you need to add a conditional introduction so that you can validly justify deriving $\bot$ from the second assumed $\neg A$ (with conditional elimination).

(Plus, you do not *technically* need to reiterate the assumption in the second subproof, but some proof checkers may require it.)

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{~~~~~1.~~\neg A}{~~~~~~~\vdots\\~~~~~k.~~\bot}\\k{+}1.~~
\neg A\to\bot\hspace{4ex}{\to}\mathsf I~1{-}(k)\\\fitch{k{+}2.~~A\hspace{8ex}}{k{+}3.~~A\hspace{8ex}\mathsf R~(k{+}2)}\\\fitch{k{+}4.~~\neg A\hspace{6.5ex}}{k{+}5.~~\bot\hspace{7.5ex}{\to}\mathsf E~(k{+}4), (k{+}1)\\k{+}6.~~A\hspace{8ex}\mathsf X~(k{+}5)}\\k{+}7.~~A\vee\neg A\hspace{5ex}\textsf{LEM}\\k{+}8.~~A\hspace{11ex}{\vee}\mathsf E~(k{+}7),(k{+}2){-}(k{+}3),(k{+}4){-}(k{+}6)}$$

Comment: Does the proof of the  principle of explosion not require  indirect proof?

Comment: No. The rule of inference is considered a fundamental in intuitionistic natural deduction. (Or as axiomatic in the [Hilbert-style calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Hilbert-style_calculus).)

Comment: @DanChristensen Indirect Proof is invalid in intuitionistic logic. It requires either LEM or Double Negation Elimination.  However, the Principle of Explosion is intuitionistically valid. It is one of the fundamental rules.